# How to build the smallest regular n-sided polygon that covers an (n-1)-sided polygon?

Tags: metric-geometry

I want to build a figure that contains seven regular polygons, from a triangle up to a nonagon, where each n-sided polygon covers, with the minimal area possible, the n-1 sided one. An added restriction is that each of them should have a horizontal base.

With this figure constructed, I'd like to study its properties (mainly the side and area of each polygon, ideally expressed as a function of the triangle's side).

I wonder if there's a way to build this, either with a rule and a compass (unlikely, I presume) or by using a dedicated software program for this effect.

Thanks.

Comment: Regular septagons and nonagons cannot be built from rule and compass, so that answers your first question. // When you say that each of them should have a horizontal base do you mean that the "bottom-most" edge of the polygons are all horizontal (and hence overlapping)?

Comment: (Please scratch the word "hence" from the parenthetical of my previous comment.)

Comment: Yes, I mean the bottom-most edge.

Answer (score 6):

To expland upon Willie Wong's question, is this what you mean by 
"each of them should have a horizontal base."?

---

[image: NestedRegPoly]

---

Or, just to use $n=3,4,5,6$, this?

---

[image: NestedPoly3456]

---

Comment: Regardless of the OP's original question: how did you generate the second picture? (In particular, did you analytically compute the vertices or did you just numerically found the solutions?)

Comment: The second picture is the way I mean it - all polygons should have an horizontal bottom-most edge, but not actually the same side. See my own (extremely crude) [rendering of the figure](http://www.farah.cl/0/3to9.png).

Comment: @WillieWong: Sorry to disappoint, but I did not code up anything formal. Consider those just approximate minimal-area enclosures; just drawings, really.

Comment: @MiguelFarah: Thank you for clarifying your question.